# How are Ricardian Contracts on EOS.IO such as the Constitution interfaced with?

Tags: ricardian, constitution

Will the full prose of each Ricardian contract be stored on-chain, or just a reference to its hash? Also, how does a distributed application developer publish a Ricardian contract that is mapped to a smart contract to signal the intention of said smart contract?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The full prose of the contract can be stored in the ABI which enables the conversion from binary -> json -> human contract with variable substitution.

That said, contracts could also incorporate other contracts by hash-reference.

Answer (score 0):

The first question, my understanding is it will store a reference to its hash, not the full prose.
and the second question, there are many details need to be discussed. maybe there will publish some ducs to explain it.

and some references, you can read some articles to understand more context:

1,Once Upon a Time: BIOS Booting an EOSIO blockchain，Thomas Cox；https://medium.com/eosio/bios-boot-eosio-blockchain-2b58b8a978a1
2,An EOS BIOS proposal , abourget；https://github.com/eosioca/eos-bios/blob/master/README.md
3,启动EOS主链，还差什么 https://steemit.com/eos/@eoshenzhen/5rrmdx-eos
4,李嘉图合约究竟讲了什么 https://steemit.com/eos/@eoshenzhen/6ipbwb